# CVC4 Expecting at most 3 arguments for operator 'ITE', found 5

Tags: cvc4

When inputting the following file to cvc4, I get the following error:

```
(error "Parse Error: <stdin>:11.221: Expecting at most 3 arguments for operator 'ITE', found 5")
```

The file `test.txt` was:

```
(declare-fun start!1 () Bool)

(assert start!1)

(declare-fun lt!2 () String)

(declare-datatypes () ( (JValue!1 (JInt!1 (v!75 (_ BitVec 32))) (JString!1 (v!76 String))) ))

(declare-fun a!0 () JValue!1)

(assert (=> start!1 (not (= lt!2 (ite false "" (ite (and (is-JString!1 a!0) (= (v!76 a!0) "")) """""" (ite (and (is-JInt!1 a!0) (= (v!75 a!0) #x00000000)) "0" (ite (and (is-JString!1 a!0) (= (v!76 a!0) "a")) """a""" lt!2))))))))
```

The command line:

```
cat test.txt | cvc4.exe
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I needed to add the option `--lang smt2.5` for the format to support double quote escaping using the new standard.

So:

```
cat test.txt | cvc4.exe --lang smt2.5
```